# Horizontal distance in scope of Battlefield 3?

Tags: battlefield-3

Does anyone know if the scale between the vertical dot distance is 1:1 with the horizontal dot distance? In simple terms:

For the time it takes the bullet to drop 1 dot, is the same it takes a player moving at constant speed to move 1 dot across the scope? I know that it all depends on the speed of the player, but is there set ratios? So for a static weapon (L96 with 12x scope):

While player is running without sprint:
1 vDot = 1hDot

while player is running with sprint: 1vDot = 1/2hDot

While player is in a vehicle: 1vDot = 1/10hDot

EDIT: Added some more info based on the answer i got.

EDIT 2: I am not asking how to snipe. I already know how to do that. I am wanting to know if there is a reliable ratio or not.

Comment: Would someone want to help me test this on the PC?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that there are a reliable ratio.. cause there are a LOT factors you have to consider..

for example:

1. the distance between you and the enemy
2. the difference in height. is your position "over" the enemy? is he on a highground?
3. the enemy movement. as you mentioned: running with(out) sprint, etc
4. your stand: stay, crouch, prone
5. enemy stand
6. the bullet drop of the weapon
7. the scope you attached to the weapon (ACOG, 8x, 12x, ...)

i think the only reliable is training. the more you play the more you get used to all of the aspects you have to consider.

EDIT:
This video shows a few tips, tricks and hints. I think this is a good video for the basics:

(sorry for my english.. i'm not a native speaker)

Comment: To improve your knowledge of bullet drop use just one weapon for a long time. It depends on your natural understanding of ballistics, but i guess it will take about 1-3 Service Stars to know the right angle/drop for 80-90% of the situations you will encounter.

Comment: I find your lack of ballistics disturbing..

Comment: All the factors you mentioned are taken care of once i know the vDot distance for the enemy. If i know his head is at 1 vDot, then it doesn't matter if he is doing anything else other than moving. Once he is moving, the hDot distance comes into play. I am trying to figure out if i know that my enemy is at 1vDot, can I assume in the time it takes the bullet to reach him while he is running horizontally across my scope, it will be 1 hDot later for a 1vDot distance?

Comment: also, +1 for the video. It kept me entertained :-)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the situation, fire a "guess" shot while looking down your scope to guage the distance and drop. Once you know the general bullet drop of shooting the bullet, you can start to rack up points by getting long distance headshots. Masterig uphill/downhill and completely level shooting is hard to do, but if you practice enough you're going to be a pretty damn good sniper the rest of the time.

Comment: That's already understood. However, what i am asking is a static situation. My question isn't about knowing how to snipe but a distinct issue. I want to know if there is a reliable ratio or not.